# Why is these code giving me an sigsegv error?

Tags: c, runtime-error

Why is these code giving me a RUNTIME  SIGSEGV ERROR. I have tried running the code and works perfectly in codeblocks but some IDE is giving me these error.

It takes a Fibonacci series then modulus each number in the series and only takes up the numbers at eve places till a single number is obtained.

for example:input 1
                  9
{0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21}->{0 1 1 2 3 5 8 3 1}->{1 2 5 3}->{2 3}->3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int n,j,k,r,o;
    o=0;


//  printf("enter the number of test cases: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int s[n];
    int a;
    a=n;

    while(n!=0)
    {


         r=k;
         int e[k/2];
         int m;
         scanf("%d",&k);//enter say 9
      if(k!=1)
            {
              int i[k];
              i[0]=0;
              i[1]=1;

              for(j=0;j<k;j++)
                  {
                     if(j>1)
                       {
                         i[j]=(i[j-2]+i[j-1])%10;
                       }


                  }


              while(r!=1)
                {
                 m=0;

                 for(j=0;j<r;j++)
                    {

                      if(j!=0)
                       {

                        if(j%2!=0)
                         {
                           e[m]=i[j];
                           m++;
                         }
                       }
                    }

                 for(j=0;j<k/2;j++)
                    {
                      i[j]=e[j];
                    }
                 r=r/2;
                }
             s[o]=e[0];
             o++;
             n--;
           }
        else
           {
             return 0;
           }


    }
    if(k!=1)
      {
        for(j=0;j<a;j++)
         {
             printf("%d\n",s[j]);
         }
      }


    return 0;
}
```

I want to know which point in the code is trigerring the error i know little about these error(like acessing array beyond bonds) can you explain me that?

Comment: Compile with the warning level maxed out (usually `-w4` or `-W4` depending on the compiler, although there are other possibilities and refinements), and fix the problems it warns out about.  One of them is quite serious.

Comment: `r=k; int e[k/2]; int m; scanf("%d",&k);`

Comment: Editing the question after answers have already been given to address the initial problem is not useful for future users looking at this post. It invalidates the answers that did solve the initial problem.

Comment: Srry i will edit it back

Comment: General advice: Running the program in a debugger should show you where the exception happens. That can be used as a starting point to search for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your k variable is uninitialized when you first access it at

```
r=k;
int e[k/2];
```

This means that it is equal to whatever happened to be stored at that memory location before. This could be any random number and is very bad.

On the next line you declare an array `e[k/2]` with size `k/2`, but since `k` was never initialized, this could be any size. If `k` happens to be negative, I get a segmentation fault at that line.

To fix this issue, you need to initialize all your variables before using them.

A segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) is what occurs if you try to access memory that isn't allocated to your program by the operating system.

To help with debugging these errors, run your code in the debugger. This can then take you directly to the line where the segmentation fault occured.

Comment: Okay so i forgot about that i did that initially and my declaration of r=k,and int e[k/2] after the scanf function but still it gives me an sigsegv error in and different ide the code works fine in codeblocks

Comment: I am writing these for codechef but getting these error again and again

Comment: After initializing `k` before using it, I can't reproduce the issue. Perhaps you need to make sure that the inputs are valid. You could add some error checking to make sure that the numbers for `n` and `k` are within a certain range for example.

Answer (score 0):

just put the `scanf("%d",&k);`above `r=k;`

> A SIGSEGV is an error(signal) caused by an invalid memory reference or a segmentation fault. You are probably trying to access an array element out of bounds or trying to use too much memory.

also. i am not sure about the `return 0;` in the else statement.
i haven't run the code so i may be mistaken but it should be `return 1;` instead of `return 0;`

```
if(j!=0)
{
      if(j%2!=0)
      {
            e[m]=i[j];
            m++;
      }
}
```

you can replace it with `if(j != 0 && j%2 != 0)`

Comment: Yeah i did that the code run and gives me the required output but when i submit the code on codechef it gives me runtime error.I entered a custom input in it which works fine

Comment: instead of defining all the variables at the top, define temporary variable in the loop itself.

Comment: i mean the variable 'j'

Comment: eg. `for(int j=0 ; ... ; ...);`

Answer (score 0):

I know this ques you are referring to... This is not how you supposed to solve it... You have to find the number which will left in O(1) time... As the odd places are being removed, we have to worry only about even places... Now those even places may become odd when divided by two repeatedly... Hence there is a fix number of steps which convert the whole array in a single element... At each point of this step even placed number is divided by 2, hence there will be only one even placed number who doesn't become odd placed in between or after these steps... You have to find this number just by looking N, at least i did the same... This is just a hint, if it is unclear , i can explain more logic in comment... Upvote

Comment: That's all okay but what if i stumble upon these thing again in the future i just want to know how to identify the  part of the code which gives me the error and how to avoid the mistake again

Comment: It's very normal to have errors like these when you're new to competitive programming...  You'll learn from them and will learn how to avoid next time... Nobody can teach you this stuff except you, just keep going and practing... Remember, a master has failed more times than you've ever tried... Happy coding